# Usage of “worth” as both adjective and noun in question sentence

Tags: adjectives, nouns

I am not sure whether i use “worth” correctly in two qurstiom below. Please correct me if those are wrong .

> How much money worth of car did you buy ? ( used as noun)
>
> How much money worth car did you buy ? ( used as adjective )

Comment: I don't know if you've seen it, but this recent question may be relevant/helpful: https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/195129/why-is-the-word-worth-too-much-confusing/

Answer (score 1):

No, those aren't correct. The first can be made grammatical, but would never actually be used, as:

> "How much money's worth of car did you buy?"

The only way to make the second grammatical would be to change it into the first (and correct it as above, as well).

We don't use the term "money's worth" in that way unless the thing being bought is something you buy a quantity of. You're just buying a car. If you made it "cars" then it wouldn't be so unnatural, but it would imply a person was buying a significant number of cars.

We use "how much money's worth of..." about petrol (gasoline), or sweets, or pretty much anything bought in bulk - particularly where the total costs is more relevant than the quantity, or where people mentally tally quantity by cost (that one is particularly the case for petrol).

If you're meaning to ask how much someone spent on their car, ask:

> "How much did your car cost?"

If they just bought it, you could make that "your new car". If you want to know how much their new car is worth (which is not necessarily the same as what it cost), ask:

> "How much is your new car worth?"